# spring batch: how to write valid data to one table, and invalid data another table

Tags: java, spring

I have a csv file like

```
day,cost
20140101, 20
2014-01-5, 20
20140101, ab
```

so there are some invalid data and I want to load the valid data into table_normal, and invalid data into table_unnormal
so the final data should be
for table of table_normal

```
day,cost
20140101, 20
```

for table of table_unnormal

```
day,cost, reason
2014-01-5, 20, 'invalid day'
20140101, ab,'invalid cost'
```

I know how to get the reason in processor, but how could be job write to different tables?

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest 3 ways to do this, none of which is very direct and easy.

a) Write you own CustomJDBCItemWriter - you can filter out any ways you want and you should be able to write some record in table table_normal and some record in table_unnormal

b) Use a CompositeItemWriter - both writers will get the "full record list" from the processor. You can then filter out the record needed in each writer. Very similar to (a)

c) If you can do 2 passes over the input - you can write you job in two steps. 
Step 1 : Read Records --> Process only bad records --> write to table_unnormal 
Step 2 : Read Records --> Process only good records --> write to table_normal

There isn't a good in-build feature to handle this scenario in spring batch directly (at-least none I am aware off)